# Tool to facilitate using hard links for versioning a large directory

Tags: linux, command-line, backup

I have a relatively large data directory. It gets updated occasionally, but usually only a small percentage of the tree changes. I'm currently updating it by using `cp -Rl previous_version/ new_version/` to recursively create hard links in `new_version/`, then I go into `new_version` and manually update the files that have changed. This is very space efficient, but tedious and I have to be careful to replace updated files with new inodes. If I accidentally modify the files it will change the previous versions.

What I'd really like is to be able to construct a new directory `updates/` that only has the updated versions of whatever files have changed, then have a hypothetical tool that I can run like this:

```
some-tool previous_version/ updates/ new_version/
```

What `some-tool` would do is construct `new_version/` using hard links from `previous_version/`, then for each file in `updates/` it would replace the existing file in `new_version/` with a hard link from `updates/`.

This would allow me to more easily and safely do what I'm doing, as well as provide nice update directories that clearly show what has changed between each version.

Does such a thing exist, or is there maybe another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Questions seeking product recommendations are [explicitly off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Changing the question from "what tool?" to "how can I do this?" may save it from being closed. I'm not voting to close (at least not yet), other users may be more zealous. You may want to read [*How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?*](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5372/432690)

Comment: I actually would prefer an open source tool. Definitely don't want a product. But I also already figured out a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is so obvious that I'm a bit embarrassed to leave this question up:

```
cp -Rl previous_version new_version
cp -Rlf updates/* new_version
```